# Filtering string arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, api

This uses Wolfram Alpha API to get planes nearby, then display it. How can I remove the plane direction and the phrase 'Slant distance'?

My code (PHP):

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
      <?php
    $url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=planes+seen+from+dallas&appid=2UJ62E-Q6RT3T89P8';

    $parser = new XMLReader;
    $parser->open($url);

    while ($parser->read()) {
        if ($parser->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {

            while ($parser->name === 'pod' && $parser->getAttribute('title') !== 'Result')
                $parser->next('pod'); // jump to the next pod node 

            if ($parser->name === 'plaintext') {
                $str = $parser->readString();
                $parser->close();    
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $lines = explode("\n", $str);
    $result = array();

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $fields = explode(' | ', $line);
        $flight = array_shift($fields);
        $flight = $flight . "<hr>"; //DELETE IF DOESN'T WORK

        if ($flight === '')
            $cols = $fields;
        elseif (isset($fields[1])) {
            $result[$flight][$cols[0]] = $fields[0];
            $result[$flight][$cols[1]] = $fields[1];
        } 
    }

    foreach($result as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo $key;
        foreach($value as $value1){

        echo $value1;
echo " &nbsp;";
}
    }
```

Sample output below:

```
slant distance  ENY flight 3278
14 miles NNW  Frontier Airlines flight 72
44 miles N  American Airlines flight 1241
15 miles NW  American Airlines flight 396
23 miles W  Atlantic Southeast Airlines flight 6104
49 miles SSE
```

What I want it to look like:

```
Frontier flight 3278
Airlines flight 72
American Airlines flight 1241
American Airlines flight 396
Atlantic Southeast Airlines flight 6104
```

Comment: The API doesn't offer a output options for the data, e.g. csv, json, xml, etc?

Comment: Yes, in XML where $url is the url to the sample api output.

Comment: Yes, I see that but the data you want is not actually in XML. It is all plaintext which makes this much more susceptible  to errors.

From

`14 miles NNW  Frontier Airlines flight 72`

you only want 

`14 miles Frontier Airlines flight 72`

and remove the one occurrence of 'Slant Distance', is that correct?

Comment: I've removed the direct request for "final code"; we encourage OPs to consider answers as hints that require further work, not code that can be used verbatim without any effort (requests for free code usually acts as a magnet for downvotes anyway). So you know, readers here are not keen on text speak either - "plz" and "thx" are other good ways to discourage quality answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
foreach($value as $value1){
        if(preg_match('~(flight\s+\d+)~mis', $value1, $flightdata) || preg_match('~\s+(.*?\s+Airlines)\s+~mis', $value1, $airlinedata)) {
            if(!empty($flightdata[1])) {
                echo $flightdata[1];
            }
            if(!empty($airlinedata[1])) {
                echo $airlinedata[1];
            }
            echo $value1 . ' &nbsp;' . "\n";
        }
```

You didn't mention the hr's in your desired output but those should be easy enough for you to remove.

Updated (untested because I deleted the file after answering):

```
<html>    
<head>    
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
<style>
    body {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<?php
$url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=planes+seen+from+dallas&appid=2UJ62E-Q6RT3T89P8';
$parser = new XMLReader;
$parser->open($url);
while ($parser->read()) {
    if ($parser->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        while ($parser->name === 'pod' && $parser->getAttribute('title') !== 'Result') {
            $parser->next('pod'); // jump to the next pod node 
        }
        if ($parser->name === 'plaintext') {
            $str = $parser->readString();
            $parser->close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
$result = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $fields = explode(' | ', $line);
    $flight = array_shift($fields);
    $flight = $flight . "<hr>"; //DELETE IF DOESN'T WORK
    if ($flight === '') {
        $cols = $fields;
    } elseif (isset($fields[1])) {
        $result[$flight][$cols[0]] = $fields[0];
        $result[$flight][$cols[1]] = $fields[1];
    } 
}
foreach($result as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($value as $value1){
        if(preg_match('~(flight\s+\d+)~mis', $value1, $flightdata) || preg_match('~\s+(.*?\s+Airlines)\s+~mis', $value1, $airlinedata)) {
            if(!empty($flightdata[1])) {
                echo $flightdata[1];
            }
            if(!empty($airlinedata[1])) {
                echo $airlinedata[1];
            }
            echo $value1 . ' &nbsp;' . "\n";
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: appears not to be working, plz give me final code for me to accept answer. Thx

Comment: Which edit is new; The one asking for the final code? The code above just goes inside of your foreach ` foreach($result as $key=>$value)
    { #put the above in here`

Comment: plz just give me the whole script. Thx

Comment: @chris86 Srry, upon validation it is fine. But running it outputs nothing!

Comment: My edit to @chris85 code gives the output the way the questioner wanted.  Most of the code was Chris85 `<html>    
<head>    
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
<style>
    body {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
Southwest Airlines flight 290<BR>ENY flight 3401<BR>United Airlines flight 1059<BR>American Airlines flight 324<BR>SkyWest Airlines flight 507<BR>`

Comment: @greg_diesel Outputting nothing, is nothing. You see what I mean?

Comment: If I get the code working, again, will you test it and confirm it works before accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2):

olivr3000,

Somehow I did manage to screw up my edit above and didn't include the code that finally worked for my testing.

Here is the code with my edits
You can see it in action at
http://hdreports.com/test/testjson.php
and the source is
http://hdreports.com/test/testjson.txt

Here it is and it works.  Sorry for the delay in getting it posted here correctly.

```
<html>    
<head>    
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
<style>
    body {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<?php
$url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=planes+seen+from+dallas&appid=2UJ62E-Q6RT3T89P8';
$parser = new XMLReader;
$parser->open($url);
while ($parser->read()) {
    if ($parser->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        while ($parser->name === 'pod' && $parser->getAttribute('title') !== 'Result') {
            $parser->next('pod'); // jump to the next pod node 
        }
        if ($parser->name === 'plaintext') {
            $str = $parser->readString();
            $parser->close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
$result = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $fields = explode(' | ', $line);
    $flight = array_shift($fields);

    if ($flight === '') {
        $cols = $fields;
    } elseif (isset($fields[1])) {
        $result[$flight][$cols[0]] = $fields[0];
        $result[$flight][$cols[1]] = $fields[1];
    } 
}
foreach($result as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key.'<BR>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olivr3000 here is an update.  I tried to edit Chris85 code to post this yesterday but my edit did not get published.  I changed the final foreach to output the airline data as you requested

```
<html>    
<head>    
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
<style>
    body {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<?php
$url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=planes+seen+from+dallas&appid=2UJ62E-Q6RT3T89P8';
$parser = new XMLReader;
$parser->open($url);
while ($parser->read()) {
    if ($parser->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        while ($parser->name === 'pod' && $parser->getAttribute('title') !== 'Result') {
            $parser->next('pod'); // jump to the next pod node 
        }
        if ($parser->name === 'plaintext') {
            $str = $parser->readString();
            $parser->close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
$result = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $fields = explode(' | ', $line);
    $flight = array_shift($fields);
    $flight = $flight . "<hr>"; //DELETE IF DOESN'T WORK
    if ($flight === '') {
        $cols = $fields;
    } elseif (isset($fields[1])) {
        $result[$flight][$cols[0]] = $fields[0];
        $result[$flight][$cols[1]] = $fields[1];
    } 
}
foreach($result as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($value as $value1){
        if(preg_match('~(flight\s+\d+)~mis', $value1, $flightdata) || preg_match('~\s+(.*?\s+Airlines)\s+~mis', $value1, $airlinedata)) {
            if(!empty($flightdata[1])) {
                echo $flightdata[1];
            }
            if(!empty($airlinedata[1])) {
                echo $airlinedata[1];
            }
            echo $value1 . ' &nbsp;' . "\n";
       }
    }
}
?>
```

which gives this HTML result

```
<html>    
<head>    
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
<style>
    body {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
American Airlines flight 1046<BR>N929FD<BR>
ENY flight 3238<BR>
Southwest Airlines flight 2477<BR>
American Airlines flight 2352<BR>
```

Comment: Still yields nothing!

Comment: Definitely works. Here is a live link to that code running. http://hdreports.com/test/testjson.php

Comment: Plz cp & paste EXACT code in the live code. I think my server might be experiencing issues.? Srry I'm hesitating to give the bounty. :(

Comment: That is the exact code. I tested it live at that link and pasted it here once it worked.

Comment: @greg_disesel here's my live code: http://olivr3000.atwebpages.com/ tested on 3 machines. Source Code: http://olivr3000.atwebpages.com/index.txt

Comment: That's Chris original code. It didn't work for me either.  Use my code from this answer instead.   Compare the last 20 or so lines. They are different

Comment: plz upload ur php file to pastebin and give me the link!

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure changed at some point between the last answer and this. If this continues to happen these will never work.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=planes+seen+from+dallas&appid=2UJ62E-Q6RT3T89P8';
$parser = new XMLReader;
$parser->open($url);
while ($parser->read()) {
    if ($parser->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        while ($parser->name === 'pod' && $parser->getAttribute('title') !== 'Result') {
            $parser->next('pod'); // jump to the next pod node 
        }
        if ($parser->name === 'plaintext') {
            $str = $parser->readString();
            $parser->close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if(preg_match('~^(.*?)\s+(flight\s+\d+)~', $line, $matches)){
        echo $matches[1] . ' ' . $matches[2] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Output via my shell....

```
United Airlines flight 1274
Delta Air Lines flight 2389
Mesa Airlines flight 3734
United Airlines flight 569
Shuttle America flight 3473
United Airlines flight 1274
Delta Air Lines flight 2389
Mesa Airlines flight 3734
United Airlines flight 569
Shuttle America flight 3473
```